# What preposition to use with file extensions?

Tags: prepositions, abbreviations

Basically, should I mentally decode file extension abbreviations, and thus:

> Documents in PDF (in format)
>   Photos according to JPEG (... group)

Alternatives:

> Shall I keep it as PDF?
>   Could it be that document is PDF, or a PDF?

Comment: Why do you want to *"decode"* it? In which sentence do you want to use them? Documents in PDF are basically not editable documents and photos in JPEG are compressed ones.

Comment: No, all of these file formats, and they should behave similarly. You don't say "Photos according to JPEG", you say "Photos in JPEG [format]"

Comment: @YohannV. to follow your example, `You can't edit that document because it's in PDF` and something like `You could store more files in/according to JPEG`.

Comment: @qarma You should say : *"You could store more photos if you convert them in JPEG"*. And your sentence about *PDF* is ok. (I would rather say *"**this** document"*).

Comment: Or, just say "PDF documents" or "JPEG images"

Comment: It seems to me that answer requires more context to be meaningful. For example, first phrase "Documents in PDF" is completed with the predicate "format are preferred", then the use of "in" as a preposition there is quite satisfactory. Similarly, if the second phrase is prepended by "Please sort", and the phrase is followed by ", TIF, GIF, JPG, and PNG", then the second example is also acceptable.  So, more information about the context of the examples, please.

Comment: Unless being very informal I generally add a noun -- "document", "image", "file", etc -- after the acronym.  This turns the acronym into an adjective, making it easier to construct your sentences.

Comment: @YohannV. No, you cannot say “if you convert them in JPEG”. You convert something ***to*** something, not _*in_ something.

Comment: I favor mental decoding, but just make sure you keep it inside your head.

Answer (score -1):

When you are talking about numeric format, and about their pros and cons, you should **not try to translate** literally but with understanding what this format **allows**.

For the two format you gave :

> You could store more photos if you convert them into JPEG.
>
> You can't edit this document because it is a PDF.

---

Anwering to your sentences in *Alternative* part:

> Shall I keep it [as it] in PDF?

*as it* saying *as it is now*

> Could it be that document is a PDF?

Comment: "convert **to** JPEGs" and "It's **a** PDF".

Comment: @Catija Let's say **into** !

Comment: That works, too... but you can't "convert something **in**" unless you're talking about a program that does the conversion for you: "Convert them in Photoshop".

Comment: @Catija I don't understand, you are obviously using a program to do it.

Comment: But when you say "Convert them in JPEG" it sounds like "JPEG" is the name of the program, not the type of file. And JPEG still needs to be pluralized.

Comment: "Shall I keep it as it in PDF?" What does this mean?

Comment: @Catija I will say *"I converted this photos into JPEG using MyAwesomeSoftware"*. I do not know what you want pluralized.

Comment: No, you would say "*I converted **these** photos into JPEG**s** using MyAwesomeSoftware.*" or "*I converted **this** photo into **a** JPEG using MyAwesomeSoftware.*"

Comment: @Catija Ok. I wrote too fast for my brain !

Comment: As a side note, I would not say "into JPEG**s**" – I would omit the "s". Same with other formats - "I converted these documents to PDF". Though the variant with "s" is acceptable, but not as widely used.

Comment: @Vilmar not as widely used? Can you support that with a source?